# how to set a project root folder when opening a repository involving jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to set a project folder as root path when opening it in jupyter notebook or jupyter lab? so that if someone wants to replicate a project, they don't have to change manually the paths in the different jupyter notebooks. Now what I do is I open the terminal on the project path, I initialize the corresponding environment, and then initialize jupyter lab. But that doesn't set any root path on the notebooks, because the path is just the notebook path and there are different folders with notebooks in the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it is not possible to access parent directories from a Jupyter notebook for [security reasons](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7751).